# Check if UITextView is truncated?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Is there anyway to check if UITextview has been truncated?  I have to use UITextView.

My textview is set to:

```
textview.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
```

and

```
textview.sizeToFit()
```

I've tried checking if

```
textview.text.containsString("...")
```

But this does not output true.

I've also tried :

```
let textSize : CGSize = textview.text.sizeForWidth(textview.frame.width, font: UIFont.mainFontThin(13))
```

^^^Then check the actual height vs the textSize.height:

```
print("textSize Height: \(textSize.height)")
print(textview.bounds.size.height)
```

Comment: That last one (`sizeForWidth`) looks plausible (assuming everything you're plugging in is consistent). When do you check the height? `sizeToFit` isn't necessarily immediate. You may have to wait for a draw cycle to complete. What does your final checks actually return. ("does not work" is not helpful. You need to give precise results.)

Comment: I wonder if the layout manager could be asked for information about truncation.

Comment: @RobNapier, sorry:) i have it print if text.containrsString...but it never prints.  I print out the textview.text also and it shows the whole string, no ellipsis.

Comment: The text will of course all be there. It just won't be displayed. You wouldn't want it to modify the text; then if you resized larger, it would be missing. Walk through how you're checking the `sizeForWidth` and why you think that's the wrong size. You're probably checking `bounds.size` at the wrong time. Though it's possible that your text view has different settings than the text you're checking (different font for instance, or different wrapping rules).